# How do I set the displayName of Firebase user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

According to the JS Auth documentation on the Firebase website, it only shows how to *get the displayName and how to update displayName.* So I tried to update it. But it is sort of not logical, because how can you update something without creating it.

So my question here is, *how can I set displayName of user during registeration?*

```js
function createUser(email, password) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
        error.message.replace(".", "");
        alert(error.message + " (" + error.code + ")");
        document.getElementById("password").value = "";
    });
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser != null) {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: document.getElementById("name").value
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("Updated");
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Error happened");
        });
    }
}
```

I have already tried this and it has been proven not to work...

Sincerely,
Farouk

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You have to chain the request:

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(result) {
  return result.user.updateProfile({
    displayName: document.getElementById("name").value
  })
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});`
```

Comment: oh I understand now

Comment: I believe this `user.updateProfile()` isn't a function there. It should be `const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` and then you can call `.updateProfile()` on the user.

Comment: I updated this based on the latest firebase JS SDK.

Comment: Or you could make the `createUser()` function `async` and then use `await` for the `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` command. The reason it doesn't work is that your `if` statement is executed before the `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` command is done. Therefore the result is always `false` for that `if` statement.

Comment: why do I have to `return` user.updateProfile(...)?

Answer (score 26):

This is what i used in firebase v9 using async await

```
// firebase-config.js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...,
  authDomain: ...,
  projectId: ...,
  storageBucket: ...,
  messagingSenderId: ...,
  appId: ...,
  measurementId: ...,
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

```
// register.js

import { auth } from "../../services/firebase-config"; 
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendEmailVerification,
  updateProfile,
} from "firebase/auth";


// handleRegister
const register = async (name, email, password) => {
    try {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).catch((err) =>
        console.log(err)
      );
      await sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser).catch((err) =>
        console.log(err)
      );
      await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { displayName: name }).catch(
        (err) => console.log(err)
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

then you just call this function onClick/onSubmit by passing `name`, `email`, and `password`

here's is my implementation using formik onSubmit

```
onSubmit={({ name, email, password }) => {
  register(name, email, password);
}}
```

or you can simply call the function in button onClick

```
<button onClick={() => register(name, email, password)}>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

I could´t use `({displayName: name})` directly (sintaxe error in editor). Then, I found another way:

```
UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
updateInfo.displayName = name;
result.user.updateProfile(updateInfo);
```

This is in Dart (I am using Firebase with Flutter).

Comment: Good answer! Nice and simple :) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
      .then((res) => {
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        return user.updateProfile({
          displayName: newUser.name
        })
      })
```

**This worked for me.**

Comment: why do I have to `return` user.updateProfile(...)?

Answer (score 4):

you need to import updateProfile from firebase/auth

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: "Jane Q. User", photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Profile updated!
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```

working for me

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Comment: this works in 2023

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(result) {
  result.user.displayName = document.getElementById("name").value;
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top, you can import updateProfile from firebase/auth.

```
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile} from "firebase/auth";
```

Then later inside of the handleSubmit function you can set the users display name.

```
const InitializedApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);      

const handleSubmit = (userInfo) => { 
        const auth = getAuth(InitializedApp);
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userInfo.email, userInfo.password)
          .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            updateProfile(user, {
              displayName: userInfo.name,
            });
            console.log(userInfo); //just to see in the console what it saved
    })
    .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode);
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    };
```