# Firebase Cloud Function - null user.displayName onCreate

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a function that will send a welcome email on user creation. I followed along to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events?authuser=0#access_user_attributes) tutorial, which says that one can access the newly created user's `displayName` with `user.displayName`, though it keeps returning `null` for me. I realized that the probable reason that this happens (correct me if I'm wrong here) is that registration and setting the user's displayName happens in two separate steps client-side and therefore when `onCreate` is triggered, `user.displayName` will naturally be null. Here's my client-side code, for reference:

```
fb.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password).then(user => {
  return user.user.updateProfile({ displayName: payload.name, });
}).catch(/* ... */);
```

What I'm looking for is a cloud function that gets triggered on `user.updateProfile`. I've looked into the `auth.user().onOperation` function (found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userbuilder?authuser=0#private-on-operation)), but when I try to deploy this function to firebase, I get the error `Error: Functions did not deploy properly.` (helpful, ikr), which I guess has something to do with the `onOperation` function being `private` (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? If so, how? Alternatively, is there a way to set the `displayName` on `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, so that I can keep using the `onCreate` function?

Here's my current `onCreate` code:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  console.log('name:', user.displayName);
});
```

And here's my attempt at the `onOperation` function:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onOperation(user => {
  console.log('user:', user);
}, 'updateProfile');
```

Comment: Same issue here. I wonder if it's just really sloppy design to have  `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` not take the `displayName` AND ALSO not having a trigger for `updateProfile()` or if this is some way to close a loophole that would save us money when using Firebase :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I where you, I wouldnt use firebase auth for user's profile. Maybe is a better idea to use a collection of `users`, where you have access to update triggers.

Normally, what I do is to have a trigger when there is new auth user, create a user in the `users`collection. With this design you could have a trigger everytime someone updates it's profile.

```
exports.onCreateAuthUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
     displayName: user.displayName,
     email: user.email,
     // any other properties 
  })

  //do other stuff
});

exports.onUpdateUser = functions
  .firestore.document('users/{id}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
     // do stuff when user's profile gets updated
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The problem is that there is no `user.displayName` in the onCreate trigger because the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function of firebase auth does not allow to pass the displayName. Writing the display name is a separate operation with the ? updateProfile()` function and there's no functions trigger for that :-|

Answer (score 7):

There is currently no Cloud Functions trigger for updating a Firebase Auth profile.  There is just onCreate and onDelete.

See: [Firebase auth onUpdate cloud function for when a user updates their email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933827/firebase-auth-onupdate-cloud-function-for-when-a-user-updates-their-email)

There is currently no way to set a user's displayName property during the creation of an account using email/password authentication.  It requires a second call to update the profile after the account is created.

See: [How do I set the displayName of Firebase user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389946/how-do-i-set-the-displayname-of-firebase-user/40429080)

Basically, you are going to have to work around these limitations.  Feel free to [contact Firebase support to file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to make this easier.